# Compute the degree of a particular morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, projective-space, grassmannian

Let $\mathbb P^n=\mathbb{CP^n}$ be complex projective space. Let $H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d))$ be the group of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$, and denote its dimension by $N(d)$. Consider the map
$$H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1))\to Gr(N(d),n)$$
$$L\mapsto H^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d-1))\cdot L$$
where $Gr$ is the Grassmannian.

My question is

> How can I compute the degree of this map?

We can talk about the degree because of Plücker ebeddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a map to $Gr(V,n)$ one needs to specify a rank $n$ quotient bundle of the trivial bundle $V \otimes O$. In your case $V = H^0(O(d))$, and the quotient bundle is 
$$
H^0(O(d)) \otimes O \to H^0(O(d-1)) \otimes O(1).
$$
Accordingly, if $f : P^n \to Gr$ is the induced map, the pullback of the tautological quotient bundle is $H^0(O(d-1)) \otimes O(1)$, hence the pullback of $O_{Gr}(1)$ is its determinant, which is isomorphic to $O(N(d-1))$. Thus, the degree is $N(d-1)$.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit or give a reference about your first statement, i.e. the map to $Gr$ is determined by the pullback of tautological quotient bundle? I can see it is similar to the case of map to projective space, but i cannot see how they are related.

Comment: This is the universal property of a Grassmannian. It can be proved in the same way as the universal property of a projective space.